# Will Windows repair my multi-boot when I format the 1st physical partition with boot sector?

Tags: windows, multi-boot

Due to historical reasons I got a laptop with Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2 partitions. (boot from external wasn´t that viable)

Nothing (Windows Repair, bootrec /whateveroption) worked when I restored only the Windows 7 and WS2k8 with Acronis TrueImage.
Don´t ask me through what idiotic error messages I went during repair tries. (Wrong Windows version,...)

So I grudgingly restored all three - with the little additional excursion that I thought changing the active partition to the Windows 7 partition would move the boot sector and let me format the Vista part... Oh no. Seems too logical for MS. (Dunno what I changed, but today it will let me format!)

**So the real question is:
Will formatting the Vista part trash things again beyond comprehension or will Windows Repair bring back the boot rec and remove Vista from the boot options?
Or should I just erase all the files to avoid trashing the boot?**

Where will the boot rec be (after repair) when I format the Vista? On 1st or 2nd partition?

And if I get drunk and install Windows 8.1 on the 1st, will anything work? ;-)

Thanks

Comment: Probably yes. It seems like you have the same problem as I have http://superuser.com/questions/771634/how-to-re-partition-old-xp-boot-drive-with-oem-partition-after-installing-win7. It looks like there's still something on that partition that Windows needs to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. More or less roaring silence here! Well, I´m used to be on my own when it gets really complicated.

Actually it occurred to me only after I talked to a friend how idiotic this piece of software is.
Gourmet situation:
With all three Windoze partitions in place I booted the 7 and thought it would be logic to switch the active partition from Vista to 7.
Though I had booted from it (7) and did the switch on itself to it, it still thought it needed to remind me that it needed a working Windows on the active partition.
Result: BOOTSECTOR NOT FOUND.

Solution: I installed the same Windows 7 on the Vista partition and it even recognized the other ones. Don´t care further.

Would have been nice if I could have used the virgin 7 to slowly migrate to it, but I have no trust at all in deactivating the old and registering the new...